# extract part of string using sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

```
ls lib/oracle-11.2.0.3.0.txt | sed 's/lib.\([oracle.*]\)\.txt/\1/'
```

It is giving the whole string instead of just oracle part until .txt What am I doing wrong?

I can do it using awk as follows, but, not sure why sed is not giving the wanted result.

```
echo "lib/oracle-11.2.0.3.0.txt" | awk -F/ '{print substr($2,1,index($0,".txt")-1);}'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`[oracle.*]` means "one of the characters <kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>.</kbd>, or <kbd>*</kbd>". Consequently, your regex will only match something like

```
lib+c.txt
```

and not the actual filename you're passing it. If you remove the `[` and `]` from the regex, then it will work fine:

```
ls lib/oracle-11.2.0.3.0.txt | sed 's/lib.\(oracle.*\)\.txt/\1/'
```

However, a much simpler way of doing that is

```
basename lib/oracle-11.2.0.3.0.txt .txt
```

or, if you really want the file to come from `stdin`:

```
ls lib/oracle-11.2.0.3.0.txt | xargs -I{} basename {} .txt
```

Answer (score 7):

Here are a few more ways of doing this:

1. Perl

   ```
   echo "lib/oracle-11.2.0.3.0.txt" | perl -pe 's/.+(oracle.+)\.txt/$1/'
   ```
2. `sed`

   ```
   echo "lib/oracle-11.2.0.3.0.txt" | sed 's/.*\(oracle.*\)\.txt/\1/'
   ```
3. `cut`

   ```
   echo "lib/oracle-11.2.0.3.0.txt" | cut -d'/' -f 2 | cut -d '.' -f 1-5
   ```
4. `basename` and `bash`

   ```
   echo "lib/oracle-11.2.0.3.0.txt" | while read n; do 
     echo $(basename ${n/.txt//}); 
   done
   ```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `cut`

```
echo "lib/oracle-11.2.0.3.0.txt" | cut -c5-19
```